# connecting an ios app to send information to a mysql database

Tags: mysql, ios, webserver

Im doing my final project which is a taxi booking service. i intend to make an ios app for the customer so that they can book a taxi. the request will then be sent to the mysql database (held at the taxi base). i want to no how can i send the information from the app to the datatbase; and the datatbase to send a confirmation message back to the app confirming the taxi has been booked!>>>>>

i have read a lot about web servers but am very confused. can i use an web server e.g. windows home server 2008? any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Seems to me the point of a homework assignment is for you to figure out how to solve the problem *on your own*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with Windows home server 2008, but I'm pretty much sure that you can use it for your project. 
If you want to keep things simple,

1. Just install XAMPP server which comes with all the components you need to work on this project including PHP and MySQL. It is one of the easiest servers to work with and most of all, its free and open source. http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html
2. Then write the business logics inside your Web App using whatever the programming language you want to (for this one PHP would be enough, or choose Java if you want to have a more complex scalable solution). Writing data to a MySQL database using PHP is very easy and you can find ton of tutorials and sample source codes in the internet.
3. Now your web app is all set, the next step is to expose these services using REST where an iPhone can communicate with your services. Use JSON for interacting with your Web server from iPhone. Again, there are tones of tutorials on how to write a JSON RESTful service using PHP.
4. Finally in your iPhone app, you can access the service exposed from the server for saving data as well as to retrieve anything from it through JSON. For making this, use a good Objective-C framework such as AFNetworking. It comes with the JSON parser as well. Ref. http://afnetworking.com

Good luck with your project !

Comment: should i make an ios app or android?

Comment: Depends on number of factors. For this customer requirement, both iOS and Android will work as expected.If you go with Android, you can use Java language which is relatively easy to learn and the community support is great. Also, you don't need to buy a Mac Machine to develop this application since you can use Eclipse with ADT plugin. But if you choose iPhone, you will need to buy a Mac Machine to run Xcode in it, and also learning Objective-C is much harder unless if you are coming from a C/C++ background. So, I would recommend Android over iPhone in this case.

Comment: Just a one more addition, if you are into Android, I'd recommend Spring For Android, it's a cool framework to kick in the project quickly when you want to bid your app through REST API.  http://projects.spring.io/spring-android/

Answer (score 1):

RESTful web services are going to be your best friend here.

Create a server side program in django or python or whstever. Connect it to a database (mysql).

You can host it on Amazon Web Services.  I think they have windows 2008 instances.  I would personally use the amazon linux ami.

Use afnetworking to invoke a get or a post on the server app and you are off to the races.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this [open source taxi project](https://github.com/sytolk/TaxiAndroidOpen)
its work with RESTful web services but its better to forget about Microsoft Windows its better to use Linux hosting for your web service.